# Transforming a button into a form ( expanding )

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, forms

In my website I have a Contacts Section and Since I don't really want a form occupying a lot of space I intend to have a regular button saying " Click me" or "Try Me" and after I press it, the button expands (not like a popup or a gallery zoom) more like just changing the width and height so it can transform into a form and the reader can just fill with the information.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script> 
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        $("div").animate({
            left: '0px',
            height: '300px',
            width: '300px'
        });
    });
});
</script> 
</head>
<body>
```

this is more or less what I intend to do, I have a button and after I press it the the button zooms so the name, email, subject fields appear.

This is my button.

```
<div class="mbr-section__container">
     <a href="#" class="btn btn-default btn-lg" role="button">Take me there!</a
</div>
```

Comment: use bootstrap modal popup http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_modal.asp

Comment: The modal is not what I intend to do, I dont want a popup I want the div to expand itself, a script that changes the values of the width and height

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is a possible solution, you can easily just remove the button on click. I am just checking for the form Height and animate the height of the form holder:

```
$("button.form-btn").on('click',function(){
  var formHeight = $(".form-holder form").height();
    $( this ).animate({opacity:0});
    $(".form-holder").animate({height:formHeight});

});
```

demo link:https://jsfiddle.net/keinchy/ua3sc09w/1/

Comment: Its not 100% like that but I cant change your code to suite my needs, insted of changing the opacity to 0 I wanted to change the overall so the form older fits inside the button

Comment: if possible, show me the end result. Kinda curious.